# How to design a region table for localization standardizations with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, standardization, iso

I am designing a database for localization standardizations.
It contains Languages, Regions, Cultures, etc.
For the region, I have a hierarchical structure that contains a name and a parent which is a parent name. Name in this case is the primary key.

The parent region is the region that contains the given region.
Each region has a parent, except "001 - World".

The query looks like the following

```
SELECT
    `Name`,
    `EnglishName`,
    `Parent`
FROM
    `locales`.`Regions`
WHERE
    `Name` in ('GU', '057', 'US', '021', '019', '009')
ORDER BY
    `Parent`
```

And query result looks like the following

| Name | EnglishName | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 009 | Oceania | 001 |
| 019 | Americas | 001 |
| 057 | Micronesia | 009 |
| 021 | Northern America | 019 |
| US | United States | 021 |
| GU | Guam | 057 |

In the following example, the parent region for Guam is Micronesia. Geographically that makes sense. Let's say if software is licensed for Micronesia, it should be available in Guam.

However, in terms of jurisdiction, it does not make sense. If software is licensed to the US, it should operate in Guam as well.

Unfortunately, this is a base table that will be used in different scenarios so I can't refer correct meaning from the use case.

What do you think that current value is and why?

Answer (score 3):

> Unfortunately, this is a base table that will be used in different scenarios

Whoops. Somebody screwed up doing the requirements analysis - welcome to the real world, where physical geography and legal jursidiction do not overlap in neat ways.

Sounds like you need to go back to your product owner/client/etc, explain that there is an issue and you are going to need to redesign things.

Comment: How would you suggest to redesign things?

Comment: I can't answer that question because I don't know your business requirements.